# How create table dynamodb with global secondary indexes

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, swagger, create-table

i wanna create table `User` by dynamoDB with some attributes which design by swagger:

```
User {
   id (string, optional): UUID of User ,
   name (string, optional),
   lastLoginedAt (string, optional),
   avatar (Avatar, optional),
}

Avatar {
   avatarId (string, optional):,
   iconUri (string, optional),
   message (string, optional),
}
```

and want `User` will response with json after putItem like below:

```
{
"id": "string",
"name": "string",
"lastLoginedAt": "2016-06-24 15:28:26",
"avatar": {
  "avatarId": "string",
  "iconUri": "string",
  "message": "string"
},
}
```

I'm begginer Dynamodb and i still stuck with create table, here my code:

```
$dynamodb->createTable([
'TableName' => 'User',
'AttributeDefinitions' => [
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'id', 'AttributeType' => 'S' ],
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'name', 'AttributeType' => 'S' ],
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'avatar', 'AttributeType' => 'S' ]
],
'KeySchema' => [
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'id', 'KeyType' => 'HASH' ],  
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'name', 'KeyType' => 'RANGE' ]
],
'GlobalSecondaryIndexes' => [
    [
        'IndexName' => 'avatarIndex',
        'KeySchema' => [
            [ 'AttributeName' => 'avatarId', 'KeyType' => 'HASH' ],  
            [ 'AttributeName' => 'id', 'KeyType' => 'RANGE' ] 
        ],
        'Projection' => [ 
            'ProjectionType' => 'INCLUDE',
            'NonKeyAttributes' => [ 'iconUri', 'message' ]
        ],
        'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
            'ReadCapacityUnits' => 5,
            'WriteCapacityUnits' => 5
        ]
    ]
],
'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
    'ReadCapacityUnits' => 5,
    'WriteCapacityUnits' => 5
]]);
```

This is errors:

```
local.ERROR: Error executing "CreateTable" on "http://172.18.0.5:8000"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST http://172.18.0.5:8000` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:{"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"Global Secondary Index hash key not specified in At (truncated...)
ValidationException (client): Global Secondary Index hash key not   specified in Attribute Definitons.Type unknown. - {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"Global Secondary Index hash key not specified in Attribute Definitons.Type unknown."}
```

Thank advance!

Comment: @HarshalBulsara i've added it

Answer (score 18):

Based on the error it seems that you forgot to add attributes in the main table, following code should work

```
$dynamodb->createTable([
'TableName' => 'User',
'AttributeDefinitions' => [
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'id', 'AttributeType' => 'S' ], 
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'name', 'AttributeType' => 'S' ],
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'avatar', 'AttributeType' => 'S' ],
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'avatarId', 'AttributeType' => 'S' ], // this attribute was missing  

],
'KeySchema' => [
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'id', 'KeyType' => 'HASH' ],  
    [ 'AttributeName' => 'name', 'KeyType' => 'RANGE' ]
],
'GlobalSecondaryIndexes' => [
    [
        'IndexName' => 'avatarIndex',
        'KeySchema' => [
            [ 'AttributeName' => 'avatarId', 'KeyType' => 'HASH' ],  
            [ 'AttributeName' => 'id', 'KeyType' => 'RANGE' ] 
        ],
        'Projection' => [ 
            'ProjectionType' => 'INCLUDE',
            'NonKeyAttributes' => [ 'iconUri', 'message' ]
        ],
        'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
            'ReadCapacityUnits' => 5,
            'WriteCapacityUnits' => 5
        ]
    ]
],
'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
    'ReadCapacityUnits' => 5,
    'WriteCapacityUnits' => 5
]]);
```

You must include GSI's hash and Range attribute in the Primary tables attribute definition. In addition to that, as mentioned by Lokesh, you can use StringSet datatype for your Avatar object.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Dynamodb you can't save a complex object. In your case avatar, you can't save it as a complex object.

But you can save avatar object JSON as string and avatar will a column with type string only.

Once you save any JSON as a string you can't create an index of the attributes inside JSON.

In your case, you should not save avatar in json format. You can create columns like avatarId, avatarIconUri and avatarMessage.

```
{
"id": "string",
"name": "string",
"lastLoginedAt": "2016-06-24 15:28:26",
"avatarId": "string",
"avatarIconUri": "string",
"avatarMessage": "string"
}



GlobalSecondaryIndexes' => [
    [
        'IndexName' => 'avatarIndex',
        'KeySchema' => [
            [ 'AttributeName' => 'avatarId', 'KeyType' => 'HASH' ],  
            [ 'AttributeName' => 'id', 'KeyType' => 'RANGE' ] 
        ],
        'Projection' => [ 
            'ProjectionType' => 'INCLUDE',
            'NonKeyAttributes' => [ 'avatarIconUri', 'avatarMessage' ]
        ],
        'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
            'ReadCapacityUnits' => 5,
            'WriteCapacityUnits' => 5
        ]
    ]
],
```